# Test the series for uniform convergence

Tags: uniform-convergence

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}$$
How to proceed? Can't we do it using partial sum method?

Answer (score 1):

The series diverges for any $x \ne 0$, by comparison to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n$.  Note that for $x > 0$, $$ \dfrac{nx/(1+n^2 x^2)}{1/n} = \dfrac{n^2 x}{1+n^2 x^2} > \dfrac{1}{2x} \ \text{when}\ n > 1/x $$

Comment: Sir could you elaborate a little

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: Sir I am not aware of this procedure..

Comment: [Comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test)